# Problem with creating an environment from .yml file, error "CondaEnvException: Pip failed" raised

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, lzma

I am trying to create an environment based on a .yml file, the name of the file is `env.yml` . I run the following snippet on terminal:

```html
conda env create -f env.yml
```

Then anaconda starts installing all packages outlined in the .yml file, until it gets to packages installed with pip. It raises the following error:

```html
Ran pip subprocess with arguments:
['/Users/danielribeiro/opt/anaconda3/envs/lz_env/bin/python', '-m', 'pip', 'install', '-U', '-r', '/Users/danielribeiro/opt/Python/condaenv.80zhk806.requirements.txt']
Pip subprocess output:
Collecting backports-lzma==0.0.13 (from -r /Users/danielribeiro/opt/Python/condaenv.80zhk806.requirements.txt (line 1))

Pip subprocess error:
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backports-lzma==0.0.13 (from -r /Users/danielribeiro/opt/Python/condaenv.80zhk806.requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for backports-lzma==0.0.13 (from -r /Users/danielribeiro/opt/Python/condaenv.80zhk806.requirements.txt (line 1))


CondaEnvException: Pip failed
```

I am not sure why the package backport-lzma==0.0.13 is not installing. I also try installing it manually with

```html
conda activate lz_env
pip install backports-lzma==0.0.13


Collecting backports-lzma==0.0.13
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement backports-lzma==0.0.13 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for backports-lzma==0.0.13
```

How do I make sure I can create the environment 'lz_env' based on the .yml file I have with all the packages contained in the file?

the .yml file is the following:

```html
name: lz_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - defaults
dependencies:
  - _ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf=0.1.0=py27_0
  - alabaster=0.7.12=py27_0
  - anaconda-client=1.7.2=py27_0
  - anaconda-navigator=1.9.6=py27_0
  - anaconda-project=0.8.2=py27_0
  - appnope=0.1.0=py27hb466136_0
  - appscript=1.0.1=py27h1de35cc_1
  - asn1crypto=0.24.0=py27_0
  - astroid=1.6.5=py27_0
  - astropy=2.0.9=py27h1d22016_0
  - atomicwrites=1.2.1=py27_0
  - attrs=18.2.0=py27h28b3542_0
  - babel=2.6.0=py27_0
  - backports=1.0=py27_1
  - backports.functools_lru_cache=1.5=py27_1
  - backports.os=0.1.1=py27_0
  - backports.shutil_get_terminal_size=1.0.0=py27_2
  - backports_abc=0.5=py27h6972548_0
  - beautifulsoup4=4.6.3=py27_0
  - bitarray=0.8.3=py27h1de35cc_0
  - bkcharts=0.2=py27haafc882_0
  - blas=1.0=mkl
  - blaze=0.11.3=py27_0
  - bleach=3.0.2=py27_0
  - blosc=1.14.4=hd9629dc_0
  - bokeh=1.0.2=py27_0
  - boto=2.49.0=py27_0
  - bottleneck=1.2.1=py27h1d22016_1
  - bzip2=1.0.6=h1de35cc_5
  - ca-certificates=2019.11.28=hecc5488_0
  - cairo=1.16.0=h0ab9d94_1001
  - cdecimal=2.3=py27h1de35cc_3
  - certifi=2019.11.28=py27_0
  - cffi=1.11.5=py27h6174b99_1
  - chardet=3.0.4=py27_1
  - click=7.0=py27_0
  - cloudpickle=0.6.1=py27_0
  - clyent=1.2.2=py27_1
  - colorama=0.4.1=py27_0
  - conda=4.8.0=py27_1
  - conda-env=2.6.0=1
  - conda-package-handling=1.6.0=py27h0b31af3_1
  - conda-verify=3.1.1=py27_0
  - configparser=3.5.0=py27hc7edf1b_0
  - contextlib2=0.5.5=py27h9cb85f4_0
  - cryptography=2.4.2=py27ha12b0ac_0
  - curl=7.63.0=ha441bb4_1000
  - cycler=0.10.0=py27hfc73c78_0
  - cython=0.29.2=py27h0a44026_0
  - cytoolz=0.9.0.1=py27h1de35cc_1
  - dask=1.0.0=py27_0
  - dask-core=1.0.0=py27_0
  - datashape=0.5.4=py27_1
  - dbus=1.13.2=h760590f_1
  - decorator=4.3.0=py27_0
  - defusedxml=0.5.0=py27_1
  - distributed=1.25.1=py27_0
  - docutils=0.14=py27h0befae3_0
  - entrypoints=0.2.3=py27_2
  - enum34=1.1.6=py27_1
  - et_xmlfile=1.0.1=py27hc42f929_0
  - expat=2.2.6=h0a44026_0
  - fastcache=1.0.2=py27h1de35cc_2
  - filelock=3.0.10=py27_0
  - flask=1.0.2=py27_1
  - flask-cors=3.0.7=py27_0
  - fontconfig=2.13.1=h1027ab8_1000
  - freetype=2.9.1=hb4e5f40_0
  - funcsigs=1.0.2=py27hb9f6266_0
  - functools32=3.2.3.2=py27_1
  - future=0.17.1=py27_0
  - futures=3.2.0=py27_0
  - get_terminal_size=1.0.0=h7520d66_0
  - gettext=0.19.8.1=h15daf44_3
  - gevent=1.3.7=py27h1de35cc_1
  - glib=2.58.3=h9d45998_1002
  - glob2=0.6=py27_1
  - gmp=6.1.2=hb37e062_1
  - gmpy2=2.0.8=py27h6ef4df4_2
  - gobject-introspection=1.56.1=py27h64a7abb_1002
  - greenlet=0.4.15=py27h1de35cc_0
  - grin=1.2.1=py27_4
  - h5py=2.8.0=py27h878fce3_3
  - hdf5=1.10.2=hfa1e0ec_1
  - heapdict=1.0.0=py27_2
  - html5lib=1.0.1=py27_0
  - icu=58.2=h4b95b61_1
  - idna=2.8=py27_0
  - imageio=2.4.1=py27_0
  - imagesize=1.1.0=py27_0
  - importlib_metadata=0.6=py27_0
  - intel-openmp=2019.1=144
  - ipaddress=1.0.22=py27_0
  - ipykernel=4.10.0=py27_0
  - ipython=5.8.0=py27_0
  - ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py27h8b9a179_0
  - ipywidgets=7.4.2=py27_0
  - isort=4.3.4=py27_0
  - itsdangerous=1.1.0=py27_0
  - jbig=2.1=h4d881f8_0
  - jdcal=1.4=py27_0
  - jedi=0.13.2=py27_0
  - jinja2=2.10=py27_0
  - jpeg=9b=he5867d9_2
  - jsonschema=2.6.0=py27hd9b497e_0
  - jupyter=1.0.0=py27_7
  - jupyter_client=5.2.4=py27_0
  - jupyter_console=5.2.0=py27_1
  - jupyter_core=4.4.0=py27_0
  - jupyterlab=0.33.11=py27_0
  - jupyterlab_launcher=0.11.2=py27h28b3542_0
  - keyring=17.0.0=py27_0
  - kiwisolver=1.0.1=py27h0a44026_0
  - krb5=1.16.1=hddcf347_7
  - lazy-object-proxy=1.3.1=py27h1de35cc_2
  - libcurl=7.63.0=h051b688_1000
  - libcxx=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libcxxabi=4.0.1=hcfea43d_1
  - libedit=3.1.20170329=hb402a30_2
  - libffi=3.2.1=h475c297_4
  - libgfortran=3.0.1=h93005f0_2
  - libiconv=1.15=hdd342a3_7
  - liblief=0.9.0=h2a1bed3_0
  - libpng=1.6.35=ha441bb4_0
  - libsodium=1.0.16=h3efe00b_0
  - libssh2=1.8.0=ha12b0ac_4
  - libtiff=4.0.9=hcb84e12_2
  - libxml2=2.9.8=hab757c2_1
  - libxslt=1.1.32=hb819dd2_0
  - linecache2=1.0.0=py27_0
  - llvmlite=0.26.0=py27h8c7ce04_0
  - locket=0.2.0=py27ha10513d_1
  - lxml=4.2.5=py27hef8c89e_0
  - lz4-c=1.8.1.2=h1de35cc_0
  - lzo=2.10=h362108e_2
  - markupsafe=1.1.0=py27h1de35cc_0
  - matplotlib=2.2.3=py27h54f8f79_0
  - mccabe=0.6.1=py27_1
  - mistune=0.8.4=py27h1de35cc_0
  - mkl=2019.1=144
  - mkl-service=1.1.2=py27hfbe908c_5
  - mkl_fft=1.0.6=py27h27c97d8_0
  - mkl_random=1.0.2=py27h27c97d8_0
  - more-itertools=4.3.0=py27_0
  - mpc=1.1.0=h6ef4df4_1
  - mpfr=4.0.1=h3018a27_3
  - mpmath=1.1.0=py27_0
  - msgpack-python=0.5.6=py27h04f5b5a_1
  - multipledispatch=0.6.0=py27_0
  - navigator-updater=0.2.1=py27_0
  - nbconvert=5.4.0=py27_1
  - nbformat=4.4.0=py27hddc86d0_0
  - ncurses=6.1=h0a44026_1
  - networkx=2.2=py27_1
  - nltk=3.4=py27_1
  - nose=1.3.7=py27_2
  - notebook=5.7.4=py27_0
  - numba=0.41.0=py27h6440ff4_0
  - numexpr=2.6.8=py27h7413580_0
  - numpy=1.15.4=py27hacdab7b_0
  - numpy-base=1.15.4=py27h6575580_0
  - numpydoc=0.8.0=py27_0
  - odo=0.5.1=py27h992a9f7_0
  - olefile=0.46=py27_0
  - openpyxl=2.5.12=py27_0
  - openssl=1.1.1d=h0b31af3_0
  - packaging=18.0=py27_0
  - pandas=0.23.4=py27h6440ff4_0
  - pandoc=1.19.2.1=ha5e8f32_1
  - pandocfilters=1.4.2=py27_1
  - parso=0.3.1=py27_0
  - partd=0.3.9=py27_0
  - path.py=11.5.0=py27_0
  - pathlib2=2.3.3=py27_0
  - patsy=0.5.1=py27_0
  - pcre=8.42=h378b8a2_0
  - pep8=1.7.1=py27_0
  - pexpect=4.6.0=py27_0
  - pickleshare=0.7.5=py27_0
  - pillow=5.3.0=py27hb68e598_0
  - pip=18.1=py27_0
  - pixman=0.38.0=h01d97ff_1003
  - pkginfo=1.4.2=py27_1
  - pluggy=0.8.0=py27_0
  - ply=3.11=py27_0
  - portaudio=19.6.0=h41429eb_1
  - prometheus_client=0.5.0=py27_0
  - prompt_toolkit=1.0.15=py27h4a7b9c2_0
  - psutil=5.4.8=py27h1de35cc_0
  - ptyprocess=0.6.0=py27_0
  - py=1.7.0=py27_0
  - py-lief=0.9.0=py27hd4eaf27_0
  - pyaudio=0.2.11=py27h1de35cc_1
  - pycodestyle=2.4.0=py27_0
  - pycosat=0.6.3=py27h1de35cc_0
  - pycparser=2.19=py27_0
  - pycrypto=2.6.1=py27h1de35cc_9
  - pycurl=7.43.0.2=py27ha12b0ac_0
  - pyflakes=2.0.0=py27_0
  - pygments=2.3.1=py27_0
  - pygobject=3.28.3=py27h21bf938_1002
  - pylint=1.9.2=py27_0
  - pyodbc=4.0.25=py27h0a44026_0
  - pyopenssl=18.0.0=py27_0
  - pyparsing=2.3.0=py27_0
  - pyqt=5.9.2=py27h655552a_2
  - pysocks=1.6.8=py27_0
  - pytables=3.4.4=py27h13cba08_0
  - pytest=4.0.2=py27_0
  - python=2.7.15=h8f8e585_6
  - python-dateutil=2.7.5=py27_0
  - python.app=2=py27_9
  - pytz=2018.7=py27_0
  - pywavelets=1.0.1=py27h1d22016_0
  - pyyaml=3.13=py27h1de35cc_0
  - pyzmq=17.1.2=py27h1de35cc_0
  - qt=5.9.7=h468cd18_1
  - qtawesome=0.5.3=py27_0
  - qtconsole=4.4.3=py27_0
  - qtpy=1.5.2=py27_0
  - readline=7.0=h1de35cc_5
  - requests=2.21.0=py27_0
  - rope=0.11.0=py27_0
  - ruamel_yaml=0.15.46=py27h1de35cc_0
  - scandir=1.9.0=py27h1de35cc_0
  - scikit-image=0.14.1=py27h0a44026_0
  - scikit-learn=0.20.1=py27h27c97d8_0
  - scipy=1.1.0=py27h1410ff5_2
  - seaborn=0.9.0=py27_0
  - send2trash=1.5.0=py27_0
  - setuptools=40.6.3=py27_0
  - simplegeneric=0.8.1=py27_2
  - singledispatch=3.4.0.3=py27he22c18d_0
  - sip=4.19.8=py27h0a44026_0
  - six=1.12.0=py27_0
  - snappy=1.1.7=he62c110_3
  - snowballstemmer=1.2.1=py27h68ac032_0
  - sortedcollections=1.0.1=py27_0
  - sortedcontainers=2.1.0=py27_0
  - sphinx=1.8.2=py27_0
  - sphinxcontrib=1.0=py27_1
  - sphinxcontrib-websupport=1.1.0=py27_1
  - spyder=3.3.2=py27_0
  - spyder-kernels=0.3.0=py27_0
  - sqlalchemy=1.2.15=py27h1de35cc_0
  - sqlite=3.26.0=ha441bb4_0
  - ssl_match_hostname=3.5.0.1=py27_2
  - statsmodels=0.9.0=py27h1d22016_0
  - subprocess32=3.5.3=py27h1de35cc_0
  - sympy=1.3=py27_0
  - tblib=1.3.2=py27ha684fc4_0
  - terminado=0.8.1=py27_1
  - testpath=0.4.2=py27_0
  - tk=8.6.8=ha441bb4_0
  - toolz=0.9.0=py27_0
  - tornado=5.1.1=py27h1de35cc_0
  - tqdm=4.28.1=py27h28b3542_0
  - traceback2=1.4.0=py27_0
  - traitlets=4.3.2=py27hcf08151_0
  - typing=3.6.6=py27_0
  - unicodecsv=0.14.1=py27h170f95c_0
  - unittest2=1.1.0=py27_0
  - unixodbc=2.3.7=h1de35cc_0
  - urllib3=1.24.1=py27_0
  - wcwidth=0.1.7=py27h817c265_0
  - webencodings=0.5.1=py27_1
  - werkzeug=0.14.1=py27_0
  - wheel=0.32.3=py27_0
  - widgetsnbextension=3.4.2=py27_0
  - wrapt=1.10.11=py27h1de35cc_2
  - wurlitzer=1.0.2=py27_0
  - xlrd=1.2.0=py27_0
  - xlsxwriter=1.1.2=py27_0
  - xlwings=0.15.1=py27_0
  - xlwt=1.2.0=py27hbeec4ae_0
  - xz=5.2.4=h1de35cc_4
  - yaml=0.1.7=hc338f04_2
  - zeromq=4.2.5=h0a44026_1
  - zict=0.1.3=py27_0
  - zlib=1.2.11=h1de35cc_3
  - pip:
    - backports-lzma==0.0.13
    - brotli==1.0.7
    - dill==0.3.1.1
    - hickle==3.4.5
    - moviepy==1.0.0
    - pipenv==2018.11.26
    - proglog==0.1.9
    - pycairo==1.18.2
    - runsnakerun==2.0.4
    - squaremap==1.0.4
    - virtualenv==16.6.0
    - virtualenv-clone==0.5.3
    - wxpython==4.0.6
    - zopfli==0.1.6
    - zstd==1.4.0.0
```

Answer (score 4):

To solve the problem, I just installed the most current version of backports-lzma by manually downloading the package into my machine, then ran the [command outlined in their documentation website](https://github.com/peterjc/backports.lzma):

```html
conda install -c conda-forge backports.lzma
```

And it worked, it installed the 0.0.14 version and the version I intended to install was 0.0.13, but for the program I'm running 0.0.14 worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the version number from "backports-lzma==0.0.13" in your yml file.
and change it to "backports-lzma". The installer will look for the default version available to it from the channels provided. Can do the same for any such error for any distribution or package.